# Correct commenting for class method return value

Tags: php, phpdoc

What would be the correct PHPDocumentor comment for a class method which returns a Boolean value if it fails and something like an array if it doesn't. Here's my code example:

```
public function getServers()
{
    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM servers');

    if($q->execute())
    {
        return $q;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return false` you should probably be `try`ing and `catch`ing these errors and recording them in an error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the [phpDocumentor manual](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html).

Example:

```
/**
 * @return array|bool some result or false if none found.
 */
public function getServers()
{   
[...]
```